# how can i recuper fdquery 7value on fdquery 4

Tags: mysql, delphi-7, delphi-xe, rad

How could I integrate these two codes to insert the value of fdquery7 in fdquery4?

```
FDQuery7.SQL.Add ('SELECT nom FROM bases.nomm ');
FDQuery7.open;
FDQuery7.First;
while not FDQuery7.EOF do
begin
  FDQuery7.Fields[0].Value;
  FDQuery7.Next;
end;

FDQuery4.SQL.Add ('INSERT INTO name(firstname)  Values ("fdquery4")');
FDQuery4.execSQL;

showmessage('insert');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use only one FDQuery to do the job like this:

```
FDQuery4.SQL.Add ('INSERT INTO name (firstname) SELECT nom FROM bases.nomm');
FDQuery4.execSQL;

showmessage('insert');
```

It will do an `INSERT` for each record at `bases.nomm` table.